# Write a program in python to fetch state of residence and marital status of 5 users

Tags: python

I have been trying to write a program in python that puts the status of 5 people and states which region that person resides in. I wrote part of my code and wanted to test out married status with one of the 3 regions, West, East, and South. The problem is even when I put the state as "NY" it is still counting it towards West, instead of East, and I don't know how to fix it. Here's my code:

```
West = 0
East = 0
South = 0
Married = married = 0
MarriedW = 0
MarriedE = 0
MarriedS = 0
NY = ny = FL = fl = MA = ma = East
TX = tx = AL = al = GA = ga = Southern
CA = ca = NV = nv = AR = ar = WA = wa = West
state1 = int(input("please enter the state where the first person resides :"))
status1 = int(input("Please enter your marital status of first person :"))
if (state1==West):
    West = West + 1
    if (status1=='Married' or 'married'):
        MarriedW = MarriedW + 1
elif (state1==East):
    East = East + 1
    if (status1=='Married' or 'married'):
        MarriedE = MarriedE + 1
elif (state1==South):
    South = South + 1
    if (status1=='Married' or 'married'):
        MarriedS = MarriedS + 1
else:
    print("The person is not counted towards Any of the following states. TX, Al, GA, NY, MA, FL, CA, NV, AR or WA")
print("The number of people who belong to Western region is :" +str(West))
print("The number of people who are married in Western region is :" +str(MarriedW))
print("The number of people who belong to the Eastern region is :" +str(East))
print("The number of people who are married in Eastern region is :" +str(MarriedE))
print("The number of people who belong to Southern region is :" +str(South))
print("The number of people who are married in Southern region is:" +str(MarriedS))
```

Comment: This is some pretty wet and wild coding, I would suggest structuring your variables into some sort of containers like dictionaries or lists to make this more manageable

Comment: Whatever `NY = ny = FL = fl = MA = ma = East` is, it should be something else. This code doesn't run as-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're assigning the states as values equaling values you already defined (East West South) which are set to 0. In other words- you're making everything equal 0 (so the first conditional checking for West will always get hit).

The code is messy but to make it work with minimal changes- set the variables of the states equal to string values and check against the string value in your conditionals like so:

```
West = 0
East = 0
South = 0
Married = married = 0
MarriedW = 0
MarriedE = 0
MarriedS = 0
NY = ny = FL = fl = MA = ma = 'East' #changed this to a string
TX = tx = AL = al = GA = ga = 'South' #changed this to a string
CA = ca = NV = nv = AR = ar = WA = wa = 'West' #changed this to a string
state1 = input("please enter the state where the first person resides :") #removed int cast
print(state1)
status1 = input("Please enter your marital status of first person :")
if (state1=='West'): #changed to check against string
    West = West + 1
    if (status1=='Married' or 'married'):
        MarriedW = MarriedW + 1
elif (state1=='East'):#changed to check against string
    East = East + 1
    if (status1=='Married' or 'married'):
        MarriedE = MarriedE + 1
elif (state1=='South'): #changed to check against string
    South = South + 1
    if (status1=='Married' or 'married'):
        MarriedS = MarriedS + 1
else:
    print("The person is not counted towards Any of the following states. TX, Al, GA, NY, MA, FL, CA, NV, AR or WA")
print("The number of people who belong to Western region is :" +str(West))
print("The number of people who are married in Western region is :" +str(MarriedW))
print("The number of people who belong to the Eastern region is :" +str(East))
print("The number of people who are married in Eastern region is :" +str(MarriedE))
print("The number of people who belong to Southern region is :" +str(South))
print("The number of people who are married in Southern region is:" +str(MarriedS))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
 if (status1=='Married' or 'married')
```

Use:

```
 if (status1=='Married' or status1 == 'married')
```

You could also remove redundant paranthesis:

```
 if status1 == 'Married' or status1 == 'married'
```

More better to use:

```
if status1.lower() == 'married'
```

Comment: Or, to further simplify, why not `if status1.lower()=='married'` and get rid of the secondary condition altogether

Comment: or `if status1 in {'married', 'Married'}:`.

Comment: This is a good catch to further help OP with their code but it doesn't answer the original question OP asked- which is why passing NY maps to west instead of east.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to check if the input from a user (in your case a state code) was fitting any of the mentioned states I think that a practical and slightly more elegant solution to this problem would be creating a list of strings for the states, e.g:

`East_states = ['NY', 'ny', 'FL', 'fl', 'MA', 'ma']`

And later check if user input, which in Python3 is a string by default, can be found in the list:

```
    state1 = input("please enter the state where the first person resides :")
    status1 = input("Please enter your marital status of first person :")
if (state1 in West_states):
    West = West + 1
    if (status1 == 'married'):
        MarriedW = MarriedW + 1'
```